# Addition of two Big-O Time Complexity items

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm hearing different things about Big-O notation, specifically addition of two Big-O notations, I need some advice.

So I have the following:

O(n^2) + O(nlog)

I have heard the answer is the following:

O(n^2 nlogn) and I have heard it's O(n^2) because the O(n^2) dominates over O(nlogn)

This is really more of an "efficiency" problem, not sure how to properly ask this.

Comment: `O(n^2)` is the right answer and you already got the explanation (domination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's O(n<sup>2</sup>). As you pointed out, it's because the O(n<sup>2</sup>) term will dwarf the O(n*log n) term. Consider, for example, when n is 1 million. n<sup>2</sup> is then 10<sup>12</sup> and n*log(n) is 20 million. The n*log(n) term is insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in some values, for example:

N = 1000

n^2 = **1,000,000**

nlog(n) = 3,000

= 1.003 million, but you'd say: yeah that's 1 million